# coldfusion uploadify http 302

Tags: coldfusion, uploadify, http-status-code-302, firefox-5

I was using uploadify v2.1.4 for my coldfusion upload multiple files. It worked well in IE 9 but occured an error http 302 in firefox 5

```
$('#uploadfile').uploadify({
    'uploader' : 'uploadify.swf',
    'script' : './upload.cfm',
    'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',
    'auto' : true,
    'multi' : true,
    'onError' : function(a, b, c, d) {
        alert("Event: "+a+", QueueID: "+b+" FileInfo: "+c.name+", "+c.size+", "+c.creationDate+",  "+c.modificationDate+", "+c.type+" Error: "+d.type+", "+d.info);
    }
});
```

and my upload.cfm

```
<cfscript>
    thisPath = ExpandPath("*.*");
    thisDirectory = GetDirectoryFromPath(thisPath);
    FileDir = thisDirectory & "uploads/";
</cfscript>

<cffile action="upload" filefield="fileData" destination = "#FileDir#" nameconflict="makeunique" mode="777">
```

Comment: HTTP Status Code 302 is not an error it is a notification of a temporary redirect. Does your ColdFusion code do a <cflocation> inside of it? <cflocation> returns a 302 to the browser so it knows where to go.

Answer (score 3):

When you're using uploadify, it will send a request from the flash player to the upload.cfm  file. Unfortunately, it doesn't always send the session details to the upload.cfm file, so if you have any sort of authentication that could be blocking the request, then you'll get an error.

Verify that you don't have any authentication mechanisms in front of your upload file (and that you're not doing a cflocation, as Jason mentioned). If you do, then you'll either need to manually pass authentication credentials to your upload form, or remove the authentication requirements from that file. I usually use the [scriptData](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/scriptdata/) property for Uploadify to send the details along to my upload script.